# Django DRF TemplateHMLRenderer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to display the django rest framework data in an html template:

**view.py**

```
class TestView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ test rest"""
    queryset = models.Pippo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PippoSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer)
    template_name = 'pippo_app/test.html'
```

**url.py**

```
app_name = 'pippo_app'
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'ertest', views.PippoView)
```

**template.html**

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>

<h1>Profile - {{ dim_spessore }}</h1>

{{ form }}


<form action="{% url 'pippo_app:pippo-list' %}" method="post">


    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>



</body></html>
```

result in :

> builtins.AttributeError AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
>   'data'

the Json call works:

> Response 200 Status: Ok

adding the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 140, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 176, in render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 107, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 203, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 85, in render_form
    return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Now I've enabled werkzeug debugger and I can see that serializer is '', so there's isn't data at all.

Another way to make the frontend to this API:

```
class Manage(TemplateView):
    """test HTML frontend """
    template_name = 'label_app/label_MAN_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Manage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['prova'] = serializers.PippoSerializer()   
        return context
```

with this **template.html**

```
{{prova}}
```

I can see data form serializer.

This is the correct approach?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the full stack trace? That'll help identify what's going wrong.

Comment: post your full `TestView`

Comment: that's all, no other lines in the TestView

Comment: Try to change this line: `{% render_form serializer%}` to `{% render_form sreializer %}`. Please pay attention to the change proposed - it is the white space before the closing percentage sign!

Comment: @cezar  tried with whitespace won't change result  {% render_form serializer %}

Comment: And `{{form}}` should be `{{ form }}`.

Comment: running werkzeuf it seems that problem is here: `return renderer.render(serializer.data, None, {'style': style})
[console ready]
>>> serializer
''
>>> 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: @cezar whitespace changes like those are irrelevant to Django. `{{form}}`, `{{ form }}`, `{{form }}` etc. are all equally valid